# Spring Rest Implementation with CORS Support - Issue with multiple requests (Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, cors, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am facing issues with the CORS support for Spring Rest Implementation.
Strange thing here is, I can login successfully with Rest API but after login, getting exception as-

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Code Snippet I am using is as following -

Configuration Class -

```
  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(new CorsInterceptor());
    }
   };
 }
```

CorsInterceptor Class -

```
public class CorsInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

 public static final String CREDENTIALS_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials";
 public static final String ORIGIN_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
 public static final String METHODS_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
 public static final String HEADERS_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
 public static final String MAX_AGE_NAME = "Access-Control-Max-Age";

 static final String ORIGIN = "Origin";

 @Override
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
  String origin = request.getHeader(ORIGIN);
  response.addHeader(ORIGIN_NAME, origin);
  response.setHeader(CREDENTIALS_NAME, "true");
  response.setHeader(METHODS_NAME, "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
  response.setHeader(HEADERS_NAME,
        "Authorization, Accept-Encoding,Cache-Control, Connection, Content-Length, Cookie,Host, If-Modified-Since, Pragma, User-Agent,Content-Type");
  response.setHeader(MAX_AGE_NAME, "3600");

  if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
  }

  return true;
}
```

Here, I am able to login successful, (first preflight request then actual request, both are working fine).
After this I am calling POST request (First preflight request is getting called), but its giving me exceptions as -

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I have tried using **CorsConfiguration** and also **CorsRegistry** as -

```
registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("")
            .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
```

But no luck.

Let me know If I am missing something here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a filter instead of an interceptor and try to change `response.addHeader(ORIGIN_NAME, origin);` to `response.addHeader(ORIGIN_NAME, "*");`

Comment: I tried that too but no luck. It gives same error message.
**First api call of login gets successful** with the methods I have tried earlier but after that I am getting the same error message as mentioned in my question above.